# Relational Active record with BELONGS_TO in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 tables called `Member` and `MemberResume`.

`MemberResume` references `Member` on the key `memberid`.

In the `MemberResume` model the relation is set like this:

```
'member' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Member', 'memberid')
```

I am trying to create a model in this manner.

```
$model=Memberresume::model()->with('member')->findAllByAttributes(array('memberid'=>$id));
```

But in the model I am not able to access the attributes of `member` table like `membername` etc., though the relational query generated seems to consider the relationship.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$model=Memberresume::model()->findAllByAttributes(
  array('memberid'=>$id), // $attributes
  array('with'=>'member') // $condition (string, array or Criteria object, I think)
);
```

[findAllByAttributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail) accepts a second "condition" parameter you can add your "with" clause to. Doing it this way should join the Member table so you can access it's attributes.

Comment: I tried this.  $model->member->membername and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to `$model =Memberresume::model()->findByPk(1);
var_dump($model->member);`